# How to map the register of vim?

Tags: vim

I use `"+` to access the system clipboard,

but the `+` is too far,

I want to use `"p` to access the system clipboard, how can I do?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:map` like this:

```
:map "p "+
```

You will also want to make sure that `"p` doesn't already do something else.